# Mongoose remove document with references

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two `Schemas`, `eventSchema` and `personSchema` as shown below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var eventSchema = Schema({
    title     : String,
    location  : String,
    startDate : Date,
    endDate   : Date
});

var personSchema = Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
    dob: Date,
    city: String,
    eventsAttended: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event' }]
});

var Event  = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

How can I remove all `eventsAttended` from a deleted `Person`?

For example, if I remove a `Person` then I expect that all events assigned to that `Person` will be removed.

This is my code:

```
  Person.findOneAndRemove({_id: req.body._id}, (err, response) => {
    // remove the events assigned to this person
  })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With mongoose you can use `pre` and `post` [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) on your schemas:

`personSchema.post('remove', removeLinkedDocuments);`

Then in the `removeLinkedDocuments` callback, you can remove all linked documents:

```
function removeLinkedDocuments(doc) {
    // doc will be the removed Person document
    Event.remove({_id: { $in: doc.eventsAttended }})
}
```

Note the middleware is only called for the following methods (refer to the linked documentation for details):

- count
- find
- findOne
- findOneAndRemove
- findOneAndUpdate
- update

To remove the documents 'manually' in your callback, you might do

```
Person.findOneAndRemove({_id: req.body._id}, (err, response) => {
    // note that if you have populated the Event documents to
    // the person documents, you have to extract the id from the
    // req.body.eventsAttended object 
    Event.remove({_id: { $in: req.body.eventsAttended }}, (err, res) => {
       ...
    })
})
```

Comment: This works perfect! Would you please also tell me how can I add a new `Event` to a `Person` ?

Comment: Mongoose supports methods like push or addToSet for subdocument arrays: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.addToSet - so in your example you might do `aPersonDoc.eventsAttended.addToSet(anEventId)` or `aPersonDoc.eventsAttended.push(anEventId)`